# "Firehouse" vs. "fire station"

Tags: differences, nouns

In the United States, is *firehouse* used specifically to refer to the fire station in small town?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think many people would say there's a formal distinction between a firehouse and a fire station, but you're probably more likely to see "firehouse" used to refer to a station in a small town. The word *firehouse* has an old-fashioned feel to it, and evokes images of Dalmatians and brass firepoles--both of which are probably present in small town fire stations to a greater degree than big ones these days.

That said, I've been known to say things like "turn left at the intersection after the firehouse" even in a big city, so it's probably as much a matter of affectation or personal preference as anything else.

Comment: AFAIK, "firehouse" is unheard of in Canada, but you might hear "fire hall".